# How to check grid checkbox ondouble click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid

i want to check the checkbox on Grid only in double click and i don't want to check or uncheck on single click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CellContentDoubleClick`  would do what you want. but you have to set your checkbox `ReadOnly` property **true** by default.  i tested this event and works fine for me. let me know if this helps you:

`CellContentDoubleClick` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(1) && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) > 0 ? 0 : 1;
        }

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = true;
    }
```

and here is my GridView desing:

[image]